# Access a string as a character array for using in strings.Join() method: GO language

Tags: string, go

I am trying to access a string as a character array or as a rune and join with some separator. What is the right way to do it.

Here are the two ways i tried but i get an error as below

```
cannot use ([]rune)(t)[i] (type rune) as type []string in argument to strings.Join
```

How does a string represented in GOLANG. Is it like a character array?

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"
    )

    func main() {
        var t = "hello"
        s := ""
        for i, rune := range t {
            s += strings.Join(rune, "\n")
        }
        fmt.Println(s)
    }



    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"
    )

    func main() {
        var t = "hello"
        s := ""
        for i := 0; i < len(t); i++ {
            s += strings.Join([]rune(t)[i], "\n")
        }
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
```

I also tried the below way.BUt, it does not work for me.

```
var t = "hello"
    s := ""
    for i := 0; i < len(t); i++ {
        s += strings.Join(string(t[i]), "\n")
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
```

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**strings.Join**](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) method expects a slice of strings as first argument, but you are giving it a rune type.

You can use the [**strings.Split**](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) method to obtain a slice of strings from a string. [Here is an example](https://play.golang.org/p/P4Bfac30uJ).